# Azure queue and table storage transactions best practics

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-queues

Using azure table storage I read about Entity Group Transactions within the same partition. Now what happens if I use the Azure Queue together with table storage. Is it possible to get handle a message from the queue, insert into table storage. If something breaks, rollback and put the message on the queue again?

Or how should I handle such a scenario with Azure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tables and queues don't have any associated transactions.

Here's some general queue usage guidance:

- Make sure queue actions are *idempotent* - that is, you'd have the same results executing a queue message more than once, with repeatable side-effects
- Set a reasonalbe queue message visibility timeout. If your task looks like it will take longer, you can extend a message's invisibility timeout. This prevents other threads / role instances from grabbing the same queue item while you're still working on it.
- For long-running tasks (or those where you want to avoid consuming a resource multiple times if possible), modify your queue message along the way, giving yourself *status hints*. For example: you have a render-video queue message: `'RENDER|Source-URL'`. you're rendering video, and it needs two passes. You've done pass 1 with results stored in a temporary blob. You could modify the message with something like `'RENDER|Source-URL|Pass1-URL'`. Now, assume something goes wrong and your rendering task fails for some reason. Later, when you pick up this message again, you can start from pass 2, instead of from the very beginning.
- You don't need to worry about putting messages back on the queue. Messages aren't actually removed from the queue until you explicitly delete them. They simply become *invisible* during the invisibility timeout period you choose. If you don't delete by the end of that period (or extend the period), the message becomes visible again for someone else to read. **Note:** At this point, once someone else reads the queue message, the original message-holder will no longer be able to delete the message.